# How do you enable the Raspberry Pi camera in Yocto

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, yocto, meta-raspberrypi

I'm trying to get my Raspberry Pi camera to work with my Yocto image.
I found [here](https://meta-raspberrypi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/extra-build-config.html#video-camera-support-with-v4l2-drivers) that I need to add the following line:

```
VIDEO_CAMERA = "1"
```

I added it to my meta's recipes-core/images/example-image.bb but still when I try to take a picture I get:

```
root@user:~# raspistill -o testshot.jpg
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
mmal: Failed to create camera component
mmal: main: Failed to create camera component
mmal: Camera is not enabled in this build. Try running "sudo raspi-config" and ensure that "camera" has been enabled
```

So it seems like it's not enabled. And `raspi-config` seems to be only available on Raspbian, in fact it's not recognised as a command.

Am I missing anything else? I can't find much info out there and I'm still new to Yocto.

Comment: Could you try to add this 'VIDEO_CAMERA = "1"' line into the local.conf file i.s.o. the image bb file?

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. Why was it supposed to work though?

Comment: Do a  'bitbake -e example-image' to check if VIDEO_CAMERA is set and what yocto is doing with it.

Comment: So for some reason before I ran bitbake -e I added the VIDEO_CAMERA = "1" line to my conf/machine/raspberry3.conf file and it started working. Then I went back to check with your -e flag and I saw that VIDEO_CAMERA was indeed included. So I tried bitbaking again with the previous conditions and it worked, so I really have no idea about what made it work. Seems like the machine's conf unlocked it..

Comment: Did `VIDEO_CAMERA = 1` install raspivid and raspistill on your system, or did you have to explicitly add them somewhere? Seems like they are not added on mine...

Comment: I thought it would come with the `userland` package of `meta-raspberrypi`, but no success...